# What is Objectified Relationship?

Tags: llblgen

I am not sure if I should be asking this here or at the programmers site. I came across "objectified relationship" while researching recursive saving in llblgen framework...I then searched stackoverflow (yes, first) and then google. I then came across a brief (related) topic on nHibernate.

I have an idea what it is but is there a detail description or explanation on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is an object itself, not just a connection. In a database the relationship would  be represented as a row in a table rather than just as a UID in a column referencing another table. In a graph the relationship would itself be a node rather than 'just' an edge.